# MySql,Php not set to UTF8

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8

I'm inserting utf-8 data to the database with this code

```
$conn = new mysqli($hostname, $username, $password, $database);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

mysqli_set_charset($conn,"utf8");

$sql = "INSERT INTO Movies (Name, Year)
        VALUES ('".$_POST["name"]."', '".$_POST["year"]."')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
```

But the data is added like this:

[image]

What should I do?

Comment: Those are entities, as far as I know mysql can't do that. You must be doing it somewhere in your code. Does `$_POST["name"]` come from a WYSIWYG? This is open to SQL injections as well. If you `var_dump` `$_POST["name"]` you will see the entity in the source code of your page. In a browser it will be rendered as the character.

Comment: can you add your db schema definition

Comment: It looks like you may be showing us the wrong code.  Your code is inserting into Name and Year columns but the data you're showing is from a table with ID and Name columns.  Do you have the code where this "Name" field from the latter table is being generated?

Answer (score 0):

This is something I think you must fix in the back end, the PHP code is perfect, but you need to configure your database to utf-8 as well. You appear to be using PHPmyAdmin, when you create or import the table, [you should see a drop down box to select the file's character set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UOgGO.png). Change this and you should be good to go!

Answer (score 0):

You can use alter command in mysql to change all the fields to utf8 format,

Please check the sql query

```
ALTER TABLE `Movies` CHANGE `Name` `Name` VARCHAR(40) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL;
```

Comment: NO!  utf32 is not utf8!

Comment: Changed as per your comment.

Answer (score 0):

That should start (end?) with Arabic 'noon' (`ن`), correct?

`&#1606;` is the "html entity" for 'noon'.

Was the user filling in an html `<form>`?  does it include a charset, such as  `<form accept-charset="UTF-8">`?  If not, that might be the solution.

Is the column/table declared `CHARACTER SET utf8` (or utf8mb4, but *not* utf32)?  It needs to be.  See `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.